# Azure WebApp Subdomain Rewrite

Tags: azure, url-rewriting

I have what should be a simple rewrite URL, that takes our subdomain and rewrites it to a path on our main website. This works fine locally in IIS. However, it does not work within our webapp, any suggestions on how to point a subdomain to a folder in Azure? All the custom domains and certs are wired up correctly in Azure, and we have several other rules that are working, just not this one for the subdomain rewrite.

```
<rule>
<match url="*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*://oursubdomain.*/*" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://ourwebsite.com/oursubdomain/{C:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's the current behavior you're seeing? Also... What is your current Custom Domain configuration? Is the main domain name and the subdomain setup on the same Azure Web App? We need more detail in order to help you.

Comment: What I am seeing is that http://oursubdomain.ourdomain.com is displaying the same content as http://oursubdomain.ourdomain.com instead of being redirected. The CNAME is correctly setup in DNS as well. Yes both the main and subdomain are both setup on the same Azure Web App. All our other rule are working correctly.

Comment: <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>

Comment: <rule name="Remove trailing slash">
          <match url="(.*)/$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>

Comment: Think we figured it out. appears you have to be explicit when rewriting subdomains. I replaced pattern="*://oursubdomain.*/*" with pattern="^oursubdomain.ourdomain.com$" and it seem it works now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Then add and accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to be explicit when rewriting sub domains inside of Azure. As 
 Azure is already using wildcard to map the sub doamain. Replacing pattern="://oursubdomain.*/" with pattern="^oursubdomain.ourdomain.com$" the rule now works correctly.